# Server 2008 R2 & Auditing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, audit

Having an issue with auditing a network for logins. I am looking for Event 4740 but the logs are not showing them. Neither on the local machines either.

I have verified that **Account Management Auditing** has been enabled and is set to **Success And Failure** and I have checked the **Logon/Logoff** policy for Account Lockout to **Success**. I have tested the account on a domain machine and the log on the machine shows the account failing but never logs that the account is locked out.

When I check the Domain Controllers it shows the account failed to login but is showing **NULL SID**. Even then it does not show the lockout event either.

Anyway to figure out why it is not logging the Lockout event with it enable to do so?

Comment: Is the account being locked out?

Comment: I may have found the answer. The NULL SID led me to create a new account and then try an lock myself out. When I did that the event started working again. Not sure what caused the NULL SID as I have done no work to it but seems to be working now.